# Can I return null value for one of the items in a Tuple?

Tags: c#, asp.net, null, tuples

I have a method which returns two values (HttpResponse and Generic object). Below is the code snippet.

In some condition I have to return one of the items as null. I tried the following condition but it didn't work.

```
internal sealed class OnlineHelper<T>
{
   internal static Tuple<T, HttpStatusCode> GetRequest(arg1, arg2...)
   {
      ....
      if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
      {
          return Tuple.Create(serializer.Deserialize<T>(response),
                     webResponse.StatusCode);
      }


      return Tuple.Create(null, webResponse.StatusCode); // Compiler error
      return Tuple.Create(default(T), webResponse.StatusCode);
      // ^- Throwing null reference exception.

   }
}
```

Comment: That wont throw a NRE, probably the code using the tuple is.

Comment: and what does the compile error tell you? something like `cannot infer types from parameters`??

Comment: Yes... its giving cannot infer types from parameters error

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you do this it works:

```
var tuple = Tuple.Create<string, int>(null, 42);
```

What you tried to was have the compiler determine the type for the `null` and it can't do that so you have to explicitly provide the generic types.

So, in your case, try this:

```
return Tuple.Create<T, HttpStatusCode>(null, webResponse.StatusCode);
```

You would also need to add the generic `class` constraint to your method to allow `null` to be cast to `T`.

```
internal static Tuple<T, HttpStatusCode> GetRequest(arg1, arg2...)
    where T : class
```

Comment: like your explanation on the compiler error - cherry on top!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the simple constructor: `new Tuple<T, HttpStatusCode>()` or `Tuple.Creare`. The tricky part here is that you need to cast null to your generic type, so it should allow nulls.

Alter your class declaration to support nulls:

```
internal sealed class OnlineHelper<T> where T: class
```

And later cast or use `default(T)`

```
return new Tuple<T, HttpStatusCode>((T)null, webResponse.StatusCode)
```

Comment: no need to cast, just use `default(T)` which will be null for reference-types (`where T : class`) anyway - the important thing is injecting the generic type to the ctor of Tuple ...

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler error stems from the fact that you never put a constraint to `T`. I could instantiate your class with `T` as `int` for example and you cannot set an `int` to `null`. So setting a `T` to `null` in your code must not compile (and it does not).

I don't know where your NRE comes from in your second try. It's absolutely correct.

```
return new Tuple<T, HttpStatusCode>(null, someErrorCode);
```

However, that would mean you'd have to constraint `T` to reference types, by using the `class` keyword (if you omit this constraint, it could be `class` or `struct`, which means it works for both reference and value types):

```
internal static Tuple<T, HttpStatusCode> GetRequest(arg1, arg2...) where T : class
{
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core and .NET Framework 4.7 you can use ValueTuple.

```
public (ApplicationUser, string) CreateUser()
{
   return (null, errMsg);
}
```